# How fast DNS Propagation can practically be?

Tags: internet

I've found via web search how info (i.e. DNS name-IP number pairing) is updated on authoritative DNS servers: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/understanding-the-domain-name-servers-46c6bcf9afa3/.

> Even if you update the records in your registrar’s/ name server’s
>   dashboard, it takes some time to reflect in all the Resolvers’ caches
>   in the world. DNS propagation can take 24–72 hours, but usually it
>   happens sooner than that since most ISPs keep the TTL low.

I compare that to the almost instant update of users ip addresses on e.g. chat apps servers and wonder - what prevents authoritative DNS servers network to update DNS-IP pairing in real time?

P.S. the reason for the question is that I'm thinking about possibility of a person having his/her identity on the Net that is as permanent and independent as internet itself now - e.g about a person leasing DNS name and pointing DNS to his/her current location for like e-mail etc w/out incurring additional hosting costs.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network.

Answer (score 3):

Let's think about the DNS system and how much traffic it sees in a given day, hour, minute.. second even.   This system is ubiquitous and global.  This is a server-client system where you query an authoritative server for his information.  Now, what would happen if every single IP packet sent to a DNS host had to be resolved in real-time.  The authoritative servers would be flooded with so many requests in a give second that they would cease to operate.

Instead, every DNS entry carries with it a TTL value, or time-to-live.  This value indicates how long the DNS cached entry should be trusted.  Once we no longer trust the entry (TTL runs out), we re-query the server to see if anything has changed.

To answer your question, how fast can we converge DNS?  While you can technically specify TTL values at very very short intervals, there are many other circumstances involved that will still slow propagation down.  Here is a link to a book excerpt that discusses the fact that DNS TTLs less than 30 minutes are ineffective and wasteful.

http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/info/minimum-ttl.html

TLDR: 30 minutes is about the smallest realistic value for DNS propagation.

Comment: Thank you. I've edited my question to add how I came to it. I just wonder that chat app connects like a billion users online and there are not that much more (like several times I guess? - could not quickly web-search info) ip addresses in the Net as a whole.  Is DNS support network so much less powerful compared to that of WhatsApp?

Comment: The link you provided talks about cache poisoning attacks - interesting, seems risks are everywhere....

Answer (score 2):

DNS propagation can be instantaneous but is hampered by caching servers. The maximum caching time is limited by a record's time-to-live value (TTL). The default TTL is 86400 seconds, taking 24 hours to time out. Some servers cache even longer than that or are cascaded, so it might take longer.

If you're planning to update a record you should lower its TTL a few days in advance to maybe 300 (5 minutes), so the old value times out quicker. Don't forget to raise it again with/after the change.